# Yii scenarios - validations aren't triggering

Tags: php, yii, yii2

```
/**
   * @inheritdoc
   */
  public function rules() {
    return [
      [['quantity', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'country', 'postal_code', 'locality', 'address'], 'required'],
      [['quantity'], 'integer'],
      [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'country', 'phone'], 'string', 'max' => 127],
      [['postal_code'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
      [['locality', 'address'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
    ];
  }

    public function scenarios() {
        return [
            'firstStep' => ['quantity', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'],
            'secondStep' => ['country', 'postal_code', 'locality', 'address', 'phone'],
        ];
    }
```

When I submit the form I get:

> Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
>
> Unknown scenario: default

Does anyone knows why? Perhaps this is not the proper way to **overwrite** the *scenario* method.

Comment: you just check which field are required or safe this one define....

Comment: Vishu Patel: didn't understand your comment sorry. Care to clarify please?

Answer (score 1):

```
 public function rules() {
return [
  [['quantity', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'country', 'postal_code', 'locality', 'address'], 'required'],
  [['quantity'], 'integer'],
  [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'country', 'phone'], 'string', 'max' => 127],
  [['postal_code'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
  [['locality', 'address'], 'string', 'max' => 255],

  [['quantity', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'], 'required', 'on' => 'firstStep'],
  [['country', 'postal_code', 'locality', 'address', 'phone'], 'required', 'on' => 'secondStep'],
];
}

 you change last two line....

 And now use scenario in your controller...

 $model->scenario = 'firstStep';

 or, 

 $model->scenario = 'secondStep';
```

Comment: I believe I don't have to use the ON if I set the scenarios Vishu.

Comment: The error that I was getting, was due to the fact that the default scenario (created by Yii was not loading) because that is NOT the proper way to overwrite the scenario.

Comment: you change in model file `[['quantity', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'], 'required', 'on' => 'firstStep'],
  [['country', 'postal_code', 'locality', 'address', 'phone'], 'required', 'on' => 'secondStep'],`

Comment: I know. :) Eventually I will have to do $model->scenario = "secondStep" or use the 'on' as you suggested. But the thing is, I need to on submit the final step, to validate ALL. So on each step, I need to validate each step, and at the final round, do a validate ALL. Or perhaps this is unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

Do you extends `ActiveRecord` in your model?

Info: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Strictly speaking, the reason why I was having this error was due to the fact that I was NOT properly overwriting the scenario method, because, doing like I did, I wouldn't preserve the overwritten method specificities.
I would do a full replace on RETURN, given this `default error`.

In order to avoid this, I have to properly doing it, as it states on the docs:

ie:

```
public function scenarios() {

            $scenarios = parent::scenarios();

            $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_FIRST_STEP] = ['quantity', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'];
            $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_SECOND_STEP] = ['country', 'postal_code', 'locality', 'address', 'phone'];

            return $scenarios;

    }
```

When we do this, the error is gone.

@Vishu Patel, however, did address the implicit issue I was having. So I will accept it's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are overriding scenarios so you lost the default scenario.
you have to do it as follow

```
public function scenarios() {
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios(); // This will cover you
    $scenarios['firstStep'] = ['quantity', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'];
    $scenarios['secondStep'] = ['country', 'postal_code', 'locality', 'address', 'phone'];
    return $scenarios;

}
```

Comment: OP already posted this as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32267549/5812455

Comment: Oh sorry. I did not notice it. but may i can keep it as more clear answer?